CRM Analytics to Data Pipeline
I have couple of datasets connected with the databrick using Salesforce Connector. Now everytime they insert the data/file it shows in CRM Analytics in Data Manager. Now I want same to be displayed in the Data Manager.
We have both the License: CRM Analytics and Data Pipeline.
Can anyone please the suggest, Where the changes are needed?
